# How to have data consistency in H2 database after scaling up the spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, redis, h2

I have a spring boot application which connects to in memory H2 database. If I have to horizontally scale up the spring boot application with say 2-3 parallel instances ( I am using docker ). How can we achieve data consistency between the H2 database of each instance. Such that even if the request goes to any instance the data in all the 3 instances of H2 database is always in synch.

Comment: Don't use an in memory DB, use a single DB instance which all of your spring boot processes connect to.

Comment: In addition to what @tgdavies mentioned what you have mentioned is scaling horizontally and not vertically. Vertically is where you upgrade the specs of a single node to achieve you non functional targets.

Comment: @DhrubajyotiGogoi Thanks. Corrected vertically to horizontally.

Comment: @tgdavies For some reason i need to use h2 in memory db only.

Comment: as soon as you restart, the entire db will disappear

Comment: @Toerktumlare Yes that is acceptable because this is a POC.

Comment: You can connect to H2 in remote but I don't think you can have a cluster of H2. H2 is meant mainly for testing purposes, not production..

Comment: You need to find out what the reason for using h2 in memory DB is, and explain it in your question.

Comment: As a proof of concept, do you really need to scale?

Answer (score 0):

H2 is a database, written in java, which supports clustering

[https://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html?highlight=clustering#clustering](https://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html?highlight=clustering&search=clustering#clustering)

but it does NOT support clustering when it comes to embedded H2. If you want to achieve data consistency, you can either run the databases outside spring, as a cluster. Or you can implement some form of distributed caching like Hazelcast between the services.

If this is a POC as you have written in the comments, and you are using docker, i would drop H2 and use a single other database in a docker container, like mongo, postgres, redis etc. that all services connect to. Will make your life a lot easier.